# simplemodal dialog on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

New to JQuery and web dev in general.
I have been trying to get the confirm override [simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) demo to work, so that it pops up with on alert on initial load of my site.

The below is the standard sample, but I have included the `$(document).ready()` function to try and fire the modal dialog on startup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link type='text/css' href='css/demo.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
<link type='text/css' href='css/confirm.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.simplemodal.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/confirm.js'></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#confirm-dialog').modal();       
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>

    <div id='content'>
        <div id='confirm-dialog'>
            <input type='button' name='confirm' class='confirm' value='Demo'/> 
        </div>

        <!-- modal content -->
        <div id='confirm'>
            <div class='header'><span>Confirm</span></div>
            <div class='message'></div>
            <div class='buttons'>
                <div class='no simplemodal-close'>No</div><div class='yes'>Yes</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- preload the images -->
        <div style='display:none'>
            <img src='img/confirm/header.gif' alt='' />
            <img src='img/confirm/button.gif' alt='' />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However, this does not fire, and from what my limited experience with Firebug, I cannot see any errors so must be my code logic that is the issue?

Comment: try removing the language attribute from the script tag.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5Q4C/). What about using `.dialog` method of jquery UI library:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link type='text/css' href='css/demo.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
<link type='text/css' href='css/confirm.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.ui.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/confirm.js'></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#confirm-dialog').dialog({modal: true});       
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>

<div id='content'>
    <div id='confirm-dialog'>
        <input type='button' name='confirm' class='confirm' value='Demo'/> 
    </div>

    <!-- modal content -->
    <div id='confirm'>
        <div class='header'><span>Confirm</span></div>
        <div class='message'></div>
        <div class='buttons'>
            <div class='no simplemodal-close'>No</div><div class='yes'>Yes</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- preload the images -->
    <div style='display:none'>
        <img src='img/confirm/header.gif' alt='' />
        <img src='img/confirm/button.gif' alt='' />
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can download jquery.ui file from [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.zip)

Comment: I still cant get this to work.  Im not familiar with JSFiddle, but if I copy this to my machine, and test in firefox with firebug, it still does not fire the modal pop-up unless I click the demo button.  I am sure this code looks very close.